# Compile error CS1705 - Referenced assembly X uses '...' which has a higher version than referenced assembly '...'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version, assembly-binding-redirect

Specific Error:

> Assembly 'X' with identity 'X, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher
>   version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions' with
>   identity 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Error is thrown when invoking method of referenced assembly in dependant assembly.

Method (in referenced assembly) used to deserialize a Memory Stream and return the result:

```
public static object Deserialize(MemoryStream stream)
    {
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
```

Invocation (in the dependant assembly) throws the above error (CS1705)

To try and solve the problem, I added an App.Config file to the referenced assembly which is a Class Library [.net framework] and added this to the Configuration:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Extensions"
                      publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                      culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.5.5"
                     newVersion="4.2.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Whichever newVersion I choose the error message remains unchanged.
I can't wrap my head around what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that I'm simply an idiot.
I had selected [.netCore] over [.netFramework] by mistake and just didn't realise it.